# GCP Stackdriver custom tags

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I am working on an application that sends logs to GCP StackDriver. I want to put custom "tags" (or summary fields) natively on my log entry. I am looking for a solution that doesn't rely on defining custom summary fields in the console, as those are not permanent, and not project-wide.

I realized that some logger have tags displayed. For example, GCF logs will show its `execution_id`. Using the following snippet, I can verify that the tags displayed depend on the name of the logger:

```py
from google.cloud import logging

client = logging.Client()

client.logger(name="custom").log_text("foobar", labels={"execution_id": "foo"})
client.logger(name="cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions").log_text("foobar", labels={"execution_id": "foo"})
```

if you filter your logs on "foobar", you will see that only the second entry has "foo" as a tag.
[image]

That tag matches the `label.execution_id` specified in the code. The problem is, I cannot add custom labels, if I add another label that is not `execution_id`, it is not displayed as a tag (but still found in the log body).

It looks like each monitored resources has its own set of tag, ie: BigQuery resources use `protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail` as tag. But I cannot find a way to specify my own resources.

Does anybody has some experience with that kind of issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've filed a Feature Request on your behalf to the product team, they'll evaluate the possibility to implement the functionality that fits your use case, you can follow up on this PIT [1], where you will be able to receive further updates from the team as well.

Keep in mind that there is no ETA, nor guarantee that this will be implemented. However, please feel free to ask for updates directly on the PIT, I would appreciate if you give my answer as accepted, if it was helpful for you.

[1]https://issuetracker.google.com/172667238

Comment: Thank you for the feature request, as there seems to be no way to do it now, that is the best I could expect

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I found was in an expanded log entry, click on a field within the JSON representation. In the resulting panel, select Add field to summary line, [image]

to get more information about this topic, please refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#custom-fields)

Additionally I found a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/160594980) opened for the product team, where the user, on that case, wants  to filter out in Stackdriver by Dataflow jobs custom labels, the reference might be useful on your use case, no ETA was shared, neither guarantee of its implementation

Comment: Thank you for your time, but as stated, I am looking for a solution that doesn't rely on summary fields, as they are not persistent and not project-wide. I am not sure about the feature request as I can filter by custom label. I can put "labels.custom_value" in the Stackdriver console, it even works with autocompletion.